# Keyboard does not rotate with device when all four interface orientations are supported

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I am experiencing an odd bug with the default iPad keyboard in my app. If the keyboard is currently being displayed and you rotate the device, the keyboard will not rotate with it. The only way to remedy this while the app is running is to rotate the device back to the previous orientation, dismiss the keyboard, rotate the device, and then click on a textfield again to bring it back up.

After scouring my code and storyboard file, the only fix I have found is turning off support for the upside down orientation in my info.plist file. The keyboard will then rotate with the device like it is supposed to. However, if I do not support all four orientations my app will not work with Split View multitasking, and that functionality is a priority based on how my app will be used.

This behavior occurs in both portrait and landscape views

[Device in landscape, keyboard still in portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogCGX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and is an `storyboard` bug related, but a weird one.

I solved the issue replacing the `Main.storyboard` with a new one using a different name (i.e. `Master.storyboard`) and then I created an empty `Main.storyboard`. So the project now has 2 `storyboards`:

- New `Main.storyboard` empty.
- `Master.storyboard` with the old stuff.

and in code I instantiate the `Master.storyboard`.

I also found another solution removing the upside down orientation but it will disable the `split view` and `multitasking` feature from the app:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68688190/3701102