# iPadOS UIToolbar wrong place after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, ipados

I'm adding a `UIToolbar` in top of the keyboard using `inputAccesoryView`:

```swift
let toolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.barStyle = .default
toolbar.isTranslucent = true
toolbar.sizeToFit()
toolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

...

textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

But when I hide the keyobard, rotate the device, the next time I open the keyboard, sometimes it shows the `UIToolbar` in the middle of the screen:

[image]

But the next time I open the keyboard, the `UIToolbar` it shows in the right place.

I don't know if it is an iPadOS bug. Any ideas how can I solve this? I'm using an `UITableViewController` to populate table with cells and text fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue unchecking the `Upside down` orientation:

[image]